# Boolean false echoes an empty string

Tags: php, boolean, strpos

I've tried everything! I'm trying to find if the user "sales administrator" is allowed in the string. I've tried exploding the string & putting it in an array, i've tried `strpos` (in code below), preg match and even `if (strpos($userAllowedString, $userRole) > -1)`. The result is always empty. The result should be false, but it's not giving back anything.

```
$userAllowedString = "Sales Manager,Sales Director,Project Manager,Developer";
$userRole = "Sales Administrator";

if(strpos($userAllowedString,$userRole) !== false) { 
     $userAllowed= true; 
} else {
     $userAllowed = false; 
}
```

Any advice?

Comment: What is it - empty? How you check that it is empty?

Comment: when i debug or echo the result it is blank

Comment: Output of the `false` value is empty string. To see real variable value use `var_dump`

Comment: If you echo, then false will be blank.... do a var_dump() if you want to see boolean false

Comment: `echo false` will be shown empty, try `var_dump(false)`

Comment: Can you try with array? 

`$a = array("Sales Manager","Sales Director","Project Manager,Developer");
$b = 'Sales Administrator';
if(in_array($a,$b)){
//true
}`

Comment: The string `Sales Administrator` does not exist in `Sales Manager,Sales Director,Project Manager,Developer`. Read the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the value like 'true' or 'false' not the `true` or `false`. Because true or false without the quote itself represent empty string.

```
$userAllowedString = "Sales Manager,Sales Director,Project Manager,Developer";
$userRole = "Sales Administrator";
$userAllowedString = explode(',', $userAllowedString);

if(in_array($userRole, $userAllowedString)) { 
     $userAllowed= 'true'; 
} else {
     $userAllowed = 'false'; 
}
echo $userAllowed; //false
```

Working example: https://3v4l.org/Zkg9b

Answer (score 1):

You could just use [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.in-array.php):

```
$userAllowedString = "Sales Manager,Sales Director,Project Manager,Developer";
$userRole = "Sales Administrator";
$userAllowed = in_array($userRole, explode(',', $userAllowedString));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to recommend php builtin function [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.in-array.php) for this task. As already said in the comment i want to add this as answer with details

```
$userAllowedString = "Sales Manager,Sales Director,Project Manager,Developer";
$userRole = "Sales Administrator";
$userAllowedString = explode(',', $userAllowedString);

if(in_array($userRole, $userAllowedString)) { 
     // True
     $userAllowed= 'true'; 
} else {
     // False
     $userAllowed = 'false'; 
}


 echo $userAllowed; //false
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `in_array()` is overkill.  Your script is working as it should.

You just aren't seeing the result when you echo the variable, because boolean `false` will output an empty string.  Boolean `true` will echo `1`.  Use something other than `echo`, like `var_export()` to display the actual boolean values.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6a0c7da167567bd2f3ef33201e398c33a3d1b825))

```
$userAllowedString = "Sales Manager,Sales Director,Project Manager,Developer";
$userRole = "Sales Administrator";

if(strpos($userAllowedString,$userRole) !== false) { 
     $userAllowed= true; 
} else {
     $userAllowed = false; 
}

echo "\n----\n";
var_export($userAllowed);
echo "\n----\n";
echo false;
echo "\n----\n";
var_export(true);
echo "\n----\n";
echo true;
```

Output:

```
----
false
----

----
true
----
1
```